# BASH - How to return parent name when a certain string is found in XML - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I have a xml file and i am searching looking for a specific string in it. when that string is found, i want to return it's parent name. here is my xml:

```
<context>
    <name>AccuCapacityApp</name>
    <message>
        <source>Capacity</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Kapazität</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Charge Level</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Sel (Yes)</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Sel (Ja)</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Esc (No)</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Esc (Nein)</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

I want to search for "unfinished" and return "Capacity" as "source" and "AccuCapacityApp" as "Main".

I have already tried doing this with python, but I was unable to get the parent name. Then I thought of doing this with SED or AWK.

I tried this:

```
grep -B 1 "unfinished" file.txt
```

And received:

```
<source>Capacity</source>
<translation type="unfinished">Kapazität</translation>
```

But I only want to print the "source" and the "name". Like this:

```
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Capacity
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Charge Level
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Sel (Yes)
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Esc (No)
```

Then I tried using SED:

```
sed -n '1h;2,4 {; H; g; };/unfinished$/p;1,3d;N;D' file.txt
```

It prints nothing. I am willing to use any command line tools that can help me get this. I have also tried XMLSTARLET and used the following code:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//*' -i 'name()' -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' -i '(position()=last())' -o '-> ' -o $'\t' -b -n file.txt
```

but it only prints this:

```
-> -> ->
```

Can anyone please let me know how I should proceed with this?

Comment: I am not sure how to use XMLSTARLET. I tried the follow code: `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//*' -i 'name()' -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' -i '(position()=last())' -o '-> '  -o $'\t' -b -n  file.txt` but it only prints this: `->  

->  


->  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the endresult should look like so I've got two **GNU awk** solutions for you:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0, /<name>(.*)<\/name>/,n){ nm=n[1] }
match($0, /<source>(.*)<\/source>/,s){ src=s[1] }
/unfinished/{ print "name: " nm, "source: " src }
```

which will give you:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Capacity
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Charge Level
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Sel (Yes)
name: AccuCapacityApp source: Esc (No)
```

On the other hand, you might want to get some xml back.

```
$ cat tst2.awk
match($0, /(<name>.*<\/name>)/,n){ nm=n[1] }
match($0, /(<source>.*<\/source>)/,s){ src=s[1] }
/unfinished/{ print nm, src }
```

in which case

```
awk -f tst2.awk input.txt
<name>AccuCapacityApp</name> <source>Capacity</source>
<name>AccuCapacityApp</name> <source>Charge Level</source>
<name>AccuCapacityApp</name> <source>Sel (Yes)</source>
<name>AccuCapacityApp</name> <source>Esc (No)</source>
```

will do the trick.

Commandline call also possible:

```
awk 'match($0, /<name>(.*)<\/name>/,n){ nm=n[1] } match($0, /<source>(.*)<\/source>/,s){ src=s[1] } /unfinished/{ print "name: " nm, "source: " src }' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your first code. It gives me: `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
awk: tst.awk: line 3: syntax error at or near ,
` And the command line call gives me: `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,`

Comment: what does `awk -V` tell you?

Comment: `awk: not an option: -V`

Comment: Ok. You're not having gnu awk, so my solution will fail you. What's your OS?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Strange: have a vagrant box ubuntu 14.04 running. `vagrant@ubuntu-16:/vagrant$ which awk
/usr/bin/awk
vagrant@ubuntu-16:/vagrant$ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.0.1`

Comment: I just tried this again: `which awk
/usr/bin/awk
` and `awk -V
awk: not an option: -V
`

Comment: do a `man awk`. What does it tell you? or a `awk -W version` should work as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153750/discussion-between-marc-lambrichs-and-john).

Comment: `awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
`

Comment: If on Ubuntu, which has mawk as default, do a `sudo apt-get install gawk`. Next, with `sudo update-alternatives --config awk` you can pick `gawk` as your default awk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what output format you expected, but printing pure values using `xmlstalet` can be done with:

```
xmlstarlet select \
    --template --value-of "//translation[@type='unfinished']/preceding::name[1]| \
                           //translation[@type='unfinished']/preceding-sibling::source[1]" \
    file.xml
```

Let's break it to smaller pieces:

`xmlstarlet select # OR xmlstarlet sel`

- Select data or query XML document

`--template --value-of`

- print value of provided XPath expression

`//translation[@type='unfinished']/preceding::name[1]`

- select first value of `<name>` element, that precedes (anywhere before) `<translation>` with attribute `type` equals to `unfinished`

`|`

- join XPath expressions with logical *OR*

`//translation[@type='unfinished']/preceding-sibling::source[1]`

- select first value of `<source>`, that directly precedes `<translation>` with attribute `type` equals to `unfinished`

Output:

```
$ xmlstarlet select --template --value-of "//translation[@type='unfinished']/preceding::name|//translation[@type='unfinished']/preceding" sibling::source" file.xml
AccuCapacityApp
Capacity
Charge Level
Sel (Yes)
Esc (No)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not clear. According to my understanding you want to print sibling and parent node which is present before **unfinished** string.If i am correct then try simpler command given below.

```
sed -n '1,/unfinished/ {/.*\/.*/!d; p;}' file1.txt | head -n-1
```

It will print:

```
<name>AccuCapacityApp</name>
        <source>Capacity</source>
```